# Rails include destroyed children in response on parent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jbuilder

Let's say I have the following parent/child models:

```
foo.rb
has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, allow_destroy: true

bar.rb
belongs_to: foo
```

In my foo_controller, I send a nested jbuilder response back to the react/redux client on create/update/destroy. The client flattens the response so it can be properly handled by the reducers. This works great for create & update.

```
foo.json.jbuilder

json.foos @foos do |foo|
  json.id foo.id
  ...
  json.bars foo.bars do |bar|
    json.id bar.id
    ...
  end
end
```

On destroy, however, the children do not get passed through in the response. I'm assuming this is because dependent: :destroy removes the children first, then the parent object. As a result, the children stay in the redux store.

Thus my question, is there a way to include the destroyed children in the response when the parent is removed? I'd prefer not to send back a flattened response as the above pattern is quite frequent in the app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should try removing `dependent: :destroy` and destroying manually prior to parent?

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work either. `foo.bars` is still nil, though `foo` is still defined after the destroy.